# Php is not loop when having another foreach inside

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I'm so tired of finding out why the code is not loop with foreach in place. 1st loop is fetching the person name from db I use while loop as usual and it works. 2nd loop I test the total action each one of them doing in a month so I use a foreach loop for each month. But the problem is here. I can't make it loop again because of no clue.

Here's my codes:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$thisYear=intval(date("Y"));

for($i=1;$i<13;$i++){
    $i=sprintf("%02d",$i);
    $monArr[]=$i;
}

//select all team members    
$sql_sTeam=mysqli_query($con,"select * from TEAMNAMES order by fname asc");
$result=array();    
while($rec_sTeam=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_sTeam)){       
    $rows['name']=$rec_sTeam['sale_fname'];//sale name

    foreach($monArr as $key=>$val){
        //$rows['data'][]=(int)$key;
        $mon=intval($val);
        //n action each member\
        $sql_mLog=mysqli_query($con,"select * from mail_log where mlog_sid='$rec_sTeam[imap_sid]' and year(mlog_dtime)='$thisYear' and month(mlog_dtime)='$mon'");
        $num_mLog=mysqli_num_rows($sql_mLog);
        $rows['data'][] =(int)$num_mLog;//(int) will remove double qoutes around numbers        
    }//foreach

    array_push($result,$rows);
}//while
echo json_encode($result);
```

There're 4 people in TEAMNAMES but this is the only result from json_encode:

```
[{"name":"Ar-eshah","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,0,0]}]
```

Please point me out of here coz I'm stuck for several hours.
Regards,

Comment: I don't know why you're not getting 4 elements in `$result`. But there's another bug: you need to set `$rows = array()` at the beginning of each iteration of the `while` loop. Otherwise, you'll keep appending to the `data` element of the same array.

Comment: Barmar, you mean I should put $rows = array() right under the while loop?

Comment: Yes, right before `$rows['name'] = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the solution that you are looking for:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$thisYear = intval(date("Y"));

for($i = 1; $i < 13; $i++){
    $i = sprintf("%02d",$i);
    $monArr[] = $i;
}

//select all team members    
$sql_sTeam = mysqli_query($con,"select * from TEAMNAMES order by fname asc");
$result=array();    
while($rec_sTeam=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_sTeam)){
    $row = array();     
    $row['name']=$rec_sTeam['sale_fname'];//sale name
    $row['data'] = array();

    foreach($monArr as $key=>$val){

        $mon=intval($val);
        //n action each member\
        $sql_mLog=mysqli_query($con,"select * from mail_log where mlog_sid='$rec_sTeam[imap_sid]' and year(mlog_dtime)='$thisYear' and month(mlog_dtime)='$mon'");
        $num_mLog=mysqli_num_rows($sql_mLog);
        $row['data'][] =(int)$num_mLog;//(int) will remove double qoutes around numbers        
    }//foreach

    $result[] = $row;
}//while
echo json_encode($result)
```

Comment: This is working John. Was array_push($result,$rows); causing a problem? Please give me some lessons on this.

Comment: No! array_push is doing the exact same thing as []. According to the documentation http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php "Note: If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function." So always prefer the [] instead if you have only one element to push. The "magic code" was the: $row = array(); Always make sure that in every loop you initialize your array/object and then push it to your array.

Comment: John, that's a bible! Thank you very much for a short but valuable lesson.

Answer (score 0):

Any MySQL errors? In this line:

```
    $sql_mLog=mysqli_query($con,"select * from mail_log 
where mlog_sid='$rec_sTeam[imap_sid]' and 
year(mlog_dtime)='$thisYear' and month(mlog_dtime)='$mon'");
```

You need to brake the string in order to add an array value or use curly braces... like this:

```
    $sql_mLog=mysqli_query($con,"select * from mail_log 
where mlog_sid='".$rec_sTeam[imap_sid]."' and 
year(mlog_dtime)='$thisYear' and month(mlog_dtime)='$mon'");
```

OR

```
    $sql_mLog=mysqli_query($con,"select * from mail_log 
where mlog_sid='{$rec_sTeam[imap_sid]}' and 
year(mlog_dtime)='{$thisYear}' and month(mlog_dtime)='{$mon}' ");
```

An example:

```
    $a = array("name"=>"predte4a");
echo "My name is: $a['name']";
// will echo My name is array()['name']
echo "My name is: {$a['name']}";
//will echo My name is predte4a
```

And do not forget the quotes in your associative array keys

Comment: Predte4a, Thanks for reply. But no error at all. :(

Comment: Well it is not actually an error, just you`ll get different strings: